# UIToolBar on top of UITabBar?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitoolbar

When in the Camera Roll section of the Photos app, you can click the top right button to edit the photos.  This replaces the bottom tab bar with three new buttons which are in a UIToolBar.

I would like to do something similar, but I cannot get my UIToolBar to be on TOP of the tab bar.  Is there a way to specify the layer order?  Or do I need to do something different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be able to add the toolbar as a subview of your key window:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:toolbarView]
```

Comment: Also works for putting a toolbar over a UINavigationBar, thanks!

Comment: Monitor and act on rotation events, relocating your view to match.

Comment: @NicHubbard, have you ever managed to make this autorotate correctly? I face the same problem right now, and resizing the toolbar (or even recreating it) doesn't seem to fix the problem...