# Replace UITabBar with UIToolBar

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I have an application with `UITabBarController` with a `UINavigationController` subview, which holds a table view. I want to be able to switch out the `UITabBarController` with a `UIToolbar` for a specific view controller when a cell is selected.

Here's an example from some other application, which reacts the same way:

[image: Initial view with UITabBarController and UINavigationController]

And when you select a table view cell:

[image: Detailed view with UIToolbar]

The detailed view controller (second screen) needs to replace the parent `UITabBarController` with an `UIToolbar`. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 5):

From [UIToolBar on top of UITabBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331339/uitoolbar-on-top-of-uitabbar) :

You may be able to add the toolbar as a subview of your key window:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:toolbarView]
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not:
`detailController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`

before pushing to the navigationstack? Your DetailController's view can have the toolbar added via code or IB.

Comment: This is by far the best option.  Although the other answers work, this one accomplishes it the best.  The problem with the other methods is that they don't support rotation.  So, if you are wanting to support autorotation, just use the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed on your view before you push it on the NavigationController stack.  It will then allow your new view to take up the entire screen.

Answer (score 1):

Although @Hector Ramos answer is correct one.

But beside this one can do the same thing in other way too.

Just make the Object of DelegateClass file & use this:

```
[DelegateClassObj.window addSubview:toolbar];
```